# Rails 3 - Moving to / Start Production Server - production database is not configured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, mongrel, production

I was looking to deploy my first rails app, and have been experiencing some issues. First off, everything works fine in the development server, so I figured I was good to go. After failed to deploy the app to my host, I tried to launch the server in production mode for the first time, receiving several errors.

Out of curiousity, I created a new app, completely fresh without me editing any code. I'm getting pretty much the same errors about my database:

```
/home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': =production database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:57:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/sweiss/testapp/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/sweiss/testapp/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /home/sweiss/testapp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /home/sweiss/testapp/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/sweiss/testapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/sweiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone experiences this while trying to launch a production server? The database.yml, just for good measure, is the following default for sqlite3:

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I verified the .yml had no tabs (not that it should auto-generated).

Anyway, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the sqlite3 gem? Sounds to me like it can't find the adapter.

Comment: I think I should be good for the sqlite3 gem: Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2) 
and also in the gemfile: gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3' It does make sense for something to be up with this though. I also simple ran "rails server" while building the app, but even rails server -e=development errors out with the same information.

Comment: I don't know if this helps (help you help me :) - but I can access the rails console for production. If I run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV:production and then seed my data. I can enter the console for production and see the data in there.

Comment: It really just seems like a missing gem... I don't know what else it would be. In rvm it shows me having the sqlite3-ruby gem, and I'm requring it in my gemfile. I don't think my database.yml should matter anyway, as I've tried putting this on heroku as well, as I read your database.yml doesn't matter due to them configuring their own. My errors logs their showed the same issue.

Comment: If you're getting the same error on Heroku something other than your configuration is definitely the matter, since as you said, they override your settings anyways. I would create a new rails project with the same name and then run a diff between the two projects and look for anything you might have changed unexpectedly.